# Virtual machine disk provisioning error

Tags: terraform, cloud-automation-manager

In ICP 2.1.0.3 and CAM 2.1.0.3 apply step of template "IBM DB2 Enterprise Server Edition V11.1 on a single virtual machine Template version 2.0" fails due to template specifies variable disk.0.thin_provisioned:  "" => "true"

```
Error: Error applying plan: 1 error(s) occurred: * vsphere_virtual_machine.DB2Node01: 1 error(s) occurred:
* vsphere_virtual_machine.DB2Node01: error reconfiguring virtual machine: 
error processing disk changes post-clone: disk.0: cannot change the value of "thin_provisioned" - (old: false new: true)
```

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template does not set the disk sub-resource attributes like `eagerly_scrub` and `thin_provisioned` and therefore terraform uses the default values (true). This does not match the disk attributes of your VMware template, hence the error. The vm disk should default the attributes to their values in the template.

CAM development will improve this template flow in next release.